# If $p(x, y)\in\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ is a polynomial such that $p(x, x^2) = 0$, then $y - x^2$ divides $p$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I'm trying to prove (directly) that if $p(x, y)\in\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ is such that $p(x, x^2) = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$, then $y - x^2\mid p(x, y)$. I say "directly" because I know is true from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, but I don't want to use this. Namely
$$
\{p(x, y)\ |\ p(x, x^2) = 0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{C}\} = I(V(y - x^2)) = \langle y - x^2\rangle
$$
which is true since $y - x^2$ is irreducible, whence $\langle y - x^2\rangle$ is radical.

It seems to be true via the [multivariate polynomial division algorithm](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=yCsDO425PC0C&pg=PA61). Namely, if we assume $p(x, y)$ is not divisible by $y - x^2$, then we get $p(x, y) = q(x, y)(y - x^2) + r(x, y)$, where $r(x, y)$ has smaller *multidegree* than $p(x, y)$, and $r(x, x^2) = 0$. Inductively, either we wind up with $y - x^2\mid p(x, y)$, or a remainder $r(x, y) < \text{multideg}(y - x^2) = (2, 1)$ with $r(x, x^2) = 0$, a contradiction.

I was wondering if there is a slicker proof than this. Any ideas?

Comment: Send $p$ and $y-x^2$ to $\mathbb{C}[x][y]$ and divide there, since $y-x^2$ is monic. Then $p(x,y)=q(x,y)(y-x^2)+r(x)$. We know that $r\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ since it must have degree strictly less than $1$. Now map this equation to $\mathbb{C}[x]$ via $(x,y)\mapsto (x,x^2)$ and you get $0=r(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a natural isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x][y]$. So you can think of $p$ as a polynomial in the variable $y$ over the ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$. The condition $p(x,x^2)=0$ then means that $y=x^2$ is a root of this polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Hence $p$ is divisible by $y-x^2$.

Comment: Ahhh of course, thanks for the help!